# Transparency of whole image at the position of an object

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes, transparency

Is there a material or render setting which makes the whole rendered image transparent at the spot of an object? I.e. not to create only a transparent object where the background is visible, but a transparent „hole“ with Alpha=0? I know that this can be achieved post-rendering by the Compositor and e.g. Cryptomatte, but I would like to define the transparent areas before rendering.
Greetings from Germany, Tschöbbel

Comment: Have you tried using the *Holdout* shader?

Comment: Looks as if this is what I need! Many thanks and Schöne Weihnachten!

Comment: Setting up [Cryptomatte](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/matte/cryptomatte.html?highlight=cryptomatte) might be easier in some cases...

Answer (score 8):

#### Holdout based on a material

The *Holdout* shader node sets the alpha to zero for the area occupied by the object in the rendered image. This is documented in [Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/holdout.html):

> The Holdout shader node is used to create a “hole” in the image with zero alpha transparency, which is useful for compositing (see [alpha channel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/glossary/index.html#term-alpha-channel)).
>
> Note that the holdout shader can only create alpha when `Properties ‣ Render ‣ Film ‣ Transparent` is enabled. If it is disabled, the holdout shader will be black.

[image: Node setup]

---

#### Holdout for a collection in the current view layer

As Jachym Michal noted, you can also use the holdout *restriction toggle* to mask all objects inside a collection for the [current view layer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/layers.html). It will not affect the visibility of the same collection in a different view layer.

1. Display the holdout restriction toggle:
   [image: Restriction toggles]
2. Activate the holdout for, e.g. Collection 2:
   [image: Holdout for collection enabled]

This approach sets the `holdout` attribute for the [`LayerCollection`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.LayerCollection.html#bpy.types.LayerCollection.holdout) in the current view layer.

Alternatively you can also set/clear the holdout from the context menu in the outliner, *if you're using Cycles as render engine*. This can be accomplished by right-clicking on the collection to open the context menu and then using either *View Layer > Set Holdout* or *View Layer > Clear Holdout*. At the time of writing this option is unavailable when using any other render engine, due to a hard coded check in `OUTLINER_MT_collection_view_layer` ([`space_outliner.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_outliner.py$155)).

[image: Outliner context menu]

Comment: Holdout can also be enabled for whole collections through the outliner *restriction toggles*. [Blender manual on restriction toggles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#restriction-columns)

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ that is another option.

Comment: @brockmann I don't know in what version you've tested this, but I'm not seeing any masking option in the submenu in 2.80, 2.81a and current master.

Comment: Set the engine to cycles @RobertGützkow I think we've found a missing menu item when using eevee.

Comment: @brockmann will check after dinner and add a a bug report if that's the case

Comment: @brockmann Seems like these context menu entry was added as a temporary option in [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rBSb0077992d2759b29b536187a226e8382b72261b6). I'll check with the other developers if there is any reason for having this inconsistency between the render engines. Eevee supports holdout for a while now, so that shouldn't be the reason. This is especially confusing for users because both *set/clear holdout* and *set/clear indirect only* aren't listed as engine-dependent settings in the manual.

Comment: Cool @RobertGützkow I personally don't see any reason why not having this in the context menu...