# How to make a material that is STRICTLY alpha channel (not transparent)

Tags: materials, transparency

I have an 3D helmet I'm placing on a Live action head... I don't want to see the underside of the helmet (since the head exists under it, I shouldn't see the underside) ... Is there a way to make a material to subtract COMPLETELY and make it go straight to alpha channel?

I do have a 3D head under the helmet to use as the material that would block/ remove the underside of the helmet.
[image]

And here's the section I want to have removed/ hidden/ Alpha Channeled
[image]

Comment: Can you explain to me exactly why you can't use transparent BSDF?  I'm pretty sure in Eevee, it literally is just an alpha value.

Comment: Alpha _is_ transparency.  You can't make a material that's variably transparent unless there's a color to apply the level of transparency to.

Comment: @WhisperingShiba If I made the head under the helmet transparent, you would still see the underside of the helmet underneath. I want to know if there's a material that will make anything straight alpha, regardless of what's behind it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161596/transparency-of-whole-image-at-the-position-of-an-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7613/create-invisibility-cloak-alpha-mask-material/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48104/can-i-make-an-object-invisible-in-cycles-without-letting-the-camera-see-what-is